# Coloured indicators defined by a time interval

Tags: colors, timers

Would it be possible to have a coloured indicator that light at each second, then starts all over again?

I would have a 4 column row in a buffer.  After a predefined time interval the background colour of the first column is changed to a green colour.  After the same elapsed time is reached, the next column will light up (the previous still coloured), until one reaches column 4, then starts all over again.

Here is an example, X means dark background colour, G means green colour.

```
XXXX    ; After time interval t (all columns off)

GXXX    ; After time interval t (one column green)

GGXX    ; After time interval t

GGGX    ; After time interval t

GGGG    ; After time interval t
```

Have started with a simple function with timers.  How can I adapt this to colour a column with a timer?

```
(defun fireclock ()
  "TODO."
  (interactive)

  (let* ( (timer1
           (run-with-timer 3 1 (lambda () (message "T")))) )

    (cancel-timer timer1)) )
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Of course you could program that if you want it. Search the Emacs Lisp Manual for information about timers, faces, and text properties.

Comment: What would I need?  Have net found much on timers.  Could you provide something I could use?

Comment: There is a whole chapter on timers called 41.11 Timers for Delayed Execution.

Comment: Found it.  Would help to have some examples using a timer,  then stopping after some time.

Comment: Stopping after some time is just calling `cancel-timer` in a timer.

Comment: When you accept an answer, you are indicating that the answer has solved your problem. It does *NOT* indicate that you can then engage in conversation, asking a whole slew of questions in comments. @db48x's answer was a not-so-subtle reminder that this site is not a free "we will program it for you" service. If you want, you can pay a freelance programmer to write that program for you. And asking  an infinite stream of questions afterwards will cost extra: you have to put in the time to understand the code, experiment on your own, search the web for answers and read!

Comment: [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7wsnoi/comment/du2w3tw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) e.g. is a simple example that I found after two minutes of searching. If you say "this does not solve my problem", you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Always same mantra, I want to get paid, over and over.  Ask for a raise if you are not getting enough money at work!

Comment: I did not find clear examples on how to use the timer by reading your link.

Comment: As I said: you are doing it wrong. Anyway, since you refuse to be helped, I'm  done trying to help you.

Comment: So one uses `setq mytimer` to set a timer rather than just calling `(run-with-timer 0 8 (lambda () (message "T")))`.  How does one stop it after four repeats?

Comment: You implement that in the most obvious way: have the function count the number of calls, and cancel itself on the fourth. If you cannot figure this sort of thing out, then you’re not actually thinking about the problem.